# How do I convert a Bitmap to byte[]?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-3.5, byte, image-uploading

Basically I am inserting an image using the listviews inserting event, trying to resize an image from the fileupload control, and then save it in a SQL database using LINQ.

I found some code to create a new bitmap of the content in the fileupload control, but this was to store it in a file on the server, from [this source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1208353.aspx),  but I need to save the bitmap back into the SQL database, which I think I need to convert back into a byte[] format.

So how do I convert the bitmap to a byte[] format?

If I am going about this the wrong way I would be grateful it you could correct me.

Here is my code:

```
            // Find the fileUpload control
            string filename = uplImage.FileName;

            // Create a bitmap in memory of the content of the fileUpload control
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(uplImage.FileContent);

            // Calculate the new image dimensions
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 100;
            int newHeight = sngRatio * newWidth;

            // Create a new bitmap which will hold the previous resized bitmap
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);

            // Create a graphic based on the new bitmap
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);

            // Set the properties for the new graphic file
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);



            PHJamesDataContext db = new PHJamesDataContext();

            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            newBMP.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Position = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];

            PHJProjectPhoto myPhoto =
                new PHJProjectPhoto
                {
                    ProjectPhoto = data,
                    OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ProjectPhotoCaption = ProjectPhotoCaptionTextBox.Text,
                    ProjectId = selectedProjectId
                };

            db.PHJProjectPhotos.InsertOnSubmit(myPhoto);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to change this block to

```
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        newBMP.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        PHJProjectPhoto myPhoto =
            new PHJProjectPhoto
            {
                ProjectPhoto = stream.ToArray(), // <<--- This will convert your stream to a byte[]
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                ProjectPhotoCaption = ProjectPhotoCaptionTextBox.Text,
                ProjectId = selectedProjectId
            };
```

Answer (score 13):

If you've got a `MemoryStream` already, just call [`MemoryStream.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to get the data out.

Comment: you gave me the right answer, but i needed a little more explanation on how to implememnt it, thank you tho

Answer (score 6):

Assuming, that your bitmap is bmp

```
byte[] data;
using(System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
   bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
   stream.Position = 0;
   data = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(data, 0, stream.Length);
   stream.Close();
}
```