# how to save bitmap in byte[] c#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, byte

I need save `bitmap` in `byte[]` with c#, how to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268013/how-do-i-convert-a-bitmap-to-byte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working code for this is

```
System.Drawing.Image originalImage = dpgraphic.image;// replace your image here i.e image bitmap
//Create empty bitmap image of original size
float width=0, height=0;
Bitmap tempBmp = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBmp);
//draw the original image on tempBmp
g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height);
//dispose originalImage and Graphics so the file is now free
g.Dispose();
originalImage.Dispose();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    tempBmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    //dpgraphic.image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

to read in

```
YourByteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes( "YourGraphic.bmp" );
```

to write out

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes( "SaveToFile.bmp", YourByteArray );
```

works for me

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx I hope you are looking for this.