# byte[] b = (byte[])(sr1.image); how to convert this image type file into binary?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am fetching data of type `image` from a MySQL database and convert it to a array of bytes.

I don't know how to handle it.

I have tried

```
byte[] b = (byte[])(sr1.image);
```

That wasn't successful. How can I convert a `image` to a `byte[]`?

Comment: Start here: [ask]. And then here: [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Bitmap to byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268013/how-do-i-convert-a-bitmap-to-byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void ImagetoBinary(string FileName)
    {

        byte[] BinaryValue = ImageBinaryConvertion.ImageToBinary(FileName);
        lblBinaryValue.Text = "Converted";

        Image Image = ImageBinaryConvertion.BinaryToImage(BinaryValue);
        pbImage.Image = Image;
    }

    private void btnImagePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = "";
        OpenFileDialog OpenDig = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenDig.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        OpenDig.FilterIndex = 1;
        OpenDig.Multiselect = true;

        if (OpenDig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileName = OpenDig.FileName;
        }
        txtImagePath.Text = FileName.ToString();
        ImagetoBinary(FileName);
    }
```

Please use this code.